# Null check operator used on a null value / Flutter firebase

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

Receiving null value from the firebase even if the collection is created

[image]

I am trying to get the "menuID" value by this code:

```
final ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                 .collection("sellers")
                 .doc(sharedPreferences!.getString("uid"))
                 .collection("menus")
                 .doc(widget.model!.menuID)
                 .collection("items");
```

I already checked `sharedPreferences!.getString("uid")` returns the correct value

the problem is with `widget.model!.menuID`
Also providing code of the model class, but I dont think problem is here

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class Menus {
  String? menuID;
  String? sellerUID;
  String? menuTitle;
  String? menuInfo;
  Timestamp? publishDate;
  String? thumbnailUrl;
  String? status;

  Menus({
    this.menuID,
    this.menuInfo,
    this.menuTitle,
    this.publishDate,
    this.sellerUID,
    this.status,
    this.thumbnailUrl,
  });

  Menus.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    menuID = json["menuID"];
    menuInfo = json["menuInfo"];
    menuTitle = json["menuTitle"];
    publishDate = json["publishDate"];
    sellerUID = json["sellerUID"];
    status = json["status"];
    thumbnailUrl = json["thumbnailUrl"];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data["menuID"] = menuID;
    data["menuInfo"] = menuInfo;
    data["menuTitle"] = menuTitle;
    data["publishDate"] = publishDate;
    data["sellerUID"] = sellerUID;
    data["status"] = status;
    data["thumbnailUrl"] = thumbnailUrl;
    return data;
  }
}
```

tried to make function saveInfo asyncronius, but it is not worked

Comment: you can try with checking null `if(widget.model!=null)widget.model!.menuID`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: can you clarify, when I put the if condition it will never execute because widget.model is always returning null